# I can't use a custom Touch Bar in a status bar macOS app

Tags: menu, macos-sierra, nstouchbar

I have an app that is displayed like a status bar app (in Info.plist "Application is agent (UIElement) = YES").

I have added a TouchBar with Interface Builder and I added some Touch Bar Buttons items on it. The problem is that the custom touch bar don't show.

To make the custom touch bar to show I need to make the main WindowController window as Is Initial Controller true, unfortunately, by doing so, the app sows also a separate window with the same content than the popup window of the menu item.

Is there a way to implement a custom Touch Bar for a status bar macOS app?

[image]

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: Hi dvdblk, not yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning touchBar to your NSApplication?
You should have IBOutlet assigned with your IB touchBar and at runtime assign it.

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTouchBar *testTouchBar;
[...]
[NSApplication sharedApplication].touchBar = _testTouchBar;
```

Comment: Hi cybek, I'm a beginner and don't know Objective-C, can you help me to translate it in Swift? The outlet I put in WindowController seems to work but the second statement I put in windowDidLoad(): "let t: NSApplication = application.shared.mainTouchBar` gives an error (Bool has not member shared). Surely I translated it wrong in Swift...

Comment: @Tel Actually I'm beginner too because I'm learning obj-c. But I hope code in swift would look like this:
    let app = NSApplication.shared();
    app.touchBar = _testTouchBar;
It looks like you used sharedApplication instead of shared in swift. And it's a method. Rest would be the same.

Comment: Hi cybek, I implemented it, but it does not seem to work. Thank you